# Unknown optimizer: Ftrl on azure databricks tf keras but other optimizers work just fine

Tags: azure, tensorflow, keras, databricks

I have built a simple ANN to do some simple upfront comparisons of different optimizer performance on my data. Code snippet is below. I'm just marching through different optimizers with default params and comparing performance on some basic measures.
I'm running tf keras on a CPU-only cluster on Azure Databricks as follows:
keras ver: 2.2.4-tf;
tensorflow ver: 1.15.0

All the keras optimizers (https://keras.io/api/optimizers/) work just fine in my code with the exception of Ftrl where I get the error:

ValueError: Unknown optimizer: Ftrl

I've tried "Ftrl", "ftrl" and setting the optimizer as a variable and calling that. No dice.

Thanks for your help

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(300, activation = 'relu', input_shape=(161,)))
model.add(Dense(300, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(300, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
             optimizer = "Ftrl",
             metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [tf.keras.optimizers.Ftrl()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Ftrl)

```
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
         optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Ftrl(),
         metrics=['accuracy'])
```